# Assign a custom number while mutating and replacing NA using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, lubridate

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
id            date      from       to         type  
  <chr>      <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr>          
 1          2011-02-21 2011-01-01 2011-12-31 NA               
 2          2013-03-11 2013-01-01 2013-12-31 NA               
 3          2015-12-31 2015-01-01 2015-12-31 last             
 4          NA         NA         NA         NA                
 5          NA         NA         NA         NA
```

I would like to calculate the range that we can shift the days backward or forward.

I wrote the below code and it works fine for `Non-NA` scenarios as shown below

```
     data %>%
        mutate(shift_back_max = (date - from) / ddays(1),
                 shift_forward_max = (to - date) / ddays(1)) %>%
        data[c("shift_back_max", "shift_forward_max")][is.na(data[c("shift_back_max", "shift_forward_max")])] <- 30   # error is here with the way I am replacing `NA` with 30
```

[image]

**I guess the problem I am facing is replacing `NA` during a %>% operation task.**

For `NA scenarios`, I would like to assign **a custom range of 30-30**.

Either you can replace `NA` with 30 (for those two columns only) or any other approach to key in 30 for NA is also fine

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image: identifier date from to type shift_back_max shift_forward_max 1 2011-02-21 2011-01-01 2011-12-31 NA 51 313 2 2013-03-11 2013-01-01 2013-12-31 NA 69 295 3 2015-12-31 2015-01-01 2015-12-31 last 364 0 4 NA NA NA NA 30 30 5 NA NA NA NA 30 30]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `NA` with 30 in `mutate` for those two columns :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(shift_back_max = (date - from) / ddays(1),
         shift_forward_max = (to - date) / ddays(1), 
         across(starts_with('shift'), tidyr::replace_na, 30))

#  id       date       from         to type shift_back_max shift_forward_max
#1  1 2011-02-21 2011-01-01 2011-12-31 <NA>             51               313
#2  2 2013-03-11 2013-01-01 2013-12-31 <NA>             69               295
#3  3 2015-12-31 2015-01-01 2015-12-31 last            364                 0
#4  4       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> <NA>             30                30
#5  5       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> <NA>             30                30
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..upvoted..will markthe answer soon..can you also share the link where i can read about across

Comment: These are good references - https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html and https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/

Comment: Hi one quick but related question. I am trying to write them to a csv file in mutate file. `summarize(shift_back_max = - min(shift_back_max, na.rm = TRUE),
            shift_forward_max = min(shift_forward_max, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() -> range_cal 
  write.csv(range_cal) 
  range_cal %>%
    print %>%
    rowwise() %>%`

Comment: I tried the below too `ungroup() %>%
  write.csv(.,file = "range_cal.csv") %>%
  print %>%` but it doesn't work

Comment: After the answer you can write `%>% write.csv('range_cal.csv')`.

Comment: `write.csv` doesn't return anything so you can't do `...some code %>% write.csv %>% some more code..` Divide your analysis into parts. Do `a <- .. %>% some code` and `write.csv(a, 'filename.csv')` and then `a %>% some more code`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219674/discussion-between-the-great-and-ronak-shah).

Comment: Here how do I link the 1st part of the code `a <- .. %>% some code and write.csv(a, 'filename.csv')` and 2nd part of the code `a %>% some more code`?

Comment: Hi, one quick question. May I know what would happen if I don't use mutate for `across` statement?

Comment: I wrote a code like below to suit my data `summarize(shift_back_max = - min(shift_back_max, na.rm = TRUE),
            shift_forward_max = min(shift_forward_max, na.rm = TRUE),
            across(starts_with("shift"), ~ ifelse(is.infinite(.x), 30 * sign(.x), .x)))`

Comment: Though the code works and replaces `-Inf` with `-30` and `Inf` with `30`, Will there be any issue because I didn't use `mutate`? Might be a bad programming practice but will it impact the results/throw any logical error?

Comment: I guess it should not since from `dplyr` 1.0.0 you can return multiple rows in `summarise`. But I guess multiple should work here as well.